# What is the correct way to convert an int with representing a decimal to a double

Tags: c++, type-conversion, precision

What is the correct way to convert an int with representing a decimal to a double?

I have an int representing for example 12,123456 as 12123456. This comes from a network device that I cannot change.

I want to convert it to double with minimal error.

The naive solution would be:
`double res = boost::numeric_cast<double>(myint) / 1000000.0;`

I think that converting myint(a huge number) to a double is more lossy than some other method because the resulting value is near 1 where dobule has more precision.

I am looking for what the least lossy method of doing this conversion is.

---

EDIT:

I didn't believe log0's answer was right.
*TL;DR* He is.

The test I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

#include <boost/random.hpp>


inline double DecimalToDouble( int64_t value, int64_t divisor )
{
    int64_t first =  value / divisor;
    int64_t second = value % divisor;

    return (double)first + (double)second / (double)divisor;
}

int main()
{
    boost::mt19937 rng;
    boost::uniform_int<int> distr( std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
        std::numeric_limits<int>::max() );
    boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937, boost::uniform_int<> > dice( rng, distr );

    int erra = 0;
    int errb = 0;
    std::cout.precision( std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10 );

    int iterations = 1000000;
    for( int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i )
    {
        int x = dice();

        double divi = 10000000.0;

        double a = x / divi;
        double b = DecimalToDouble( x, 10000000 );

        if( (int)(a * divi) != x )
        {

            //std::cout << "ERROR AT A:" << x << '\t' << a << '\t' << b << std::endl;
            erra++;
        }

        if( (int)(b * divi) != x )
        {
            //std::cout << "ERROR AT B:" << x << '\t'  << a << '\t' << b << std::endl;
            errb++;
        }
    }

    std::cout.precision( 10 );
    std::cout << "A:" << (erra / (double)iterations) * 100.0 << "% B:"
            << (errb / (double)iterations) * 100.0 << "%" << std::endl;


    char stop;
    std::cin >> stop;
}
```

Result on Win7x64 VS2010: A:6.4997% B:6.5188%

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Sorry for unclear question, see edit.

Comment: What do you mean by "without losses"?

Comment: To elaborate on @Slava's comment, doubles come with loss -- that's by design, if you don't want that, use alternate fixed-point types.

Comment: I assume that converting a large integer (perhaps even larger than my example) to a floating point type results in a larger conversion error than some other method as the floating point types are most accurate near 1.

Comment: @akaltar, nope, the range of (even 64 or 128-bits wide) integers versus floating point is ridiculous. Floating-point is fast but can yield imprecise results, fixed-point is far slower but yields accurate results. Pick your poison.

Comment: I have decided I am using double for storage as its faster to use, but the data I am getting comes from `int32_t`. I want to convert it to double with minimal error.

Comment: I think `double` mantissa should be big enough to represent `int32_t` adequately. Of course you need to properly round your double when you output. And why do you need `boost::numeric_cast`? `myint/1E6` should be enough

Comment: The least lossy method of converting it is not converting it at all.

Comment: @Slava I think that should be an answer then.

Comment: I agree with @tobi303. Your problem statement 'I want to convert it to double without losses' embodies a contradiction in terms. I would store it as is.

Comment: @EJP You're right. I used wrong wording. I meant with minimal conversion error.

Comment: You say you want the result as a double. In this case, doing myint / 1000000.0, the compiler will do its job and set res to the double value the closest to the actual result. If you don't necessarily want the result as a double, why not just keeping an int ? it will be a lossless representation.

Comment: I'm not sure your test is valid (while log0 answer is correct). First, if you are using `int64_t` you should compare with `long double`s and second, using `round(a * divi) != x` instead of truncating to int would drop your percentages to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> double res = myint / 1000000.0;

That's the job of the compiler to set res to the closest representable value of the result.

Comment: I confirmed your answer with a test. It is the best method I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is always a difference between what a numerical value means for you and what representation available from the language you use in your code. Most of the time it is just not as obvious as in this case. What I want to say is: If you have an `int` whose value is `12123456` then this is already a representation of the actual value `12.123456`. The only reason I could imagine to convert it to a `double` is to use floating point arithmetics (especially division) otherwise I would just stay with the `int`.

TL;DR: If possible I would try to avoid the conversion. If you really want to do it, imho log0's answer is perfectly valid.